# ASP.NET Core Web API appsettings for specific environments

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

As I understood, ASP.NET Core Web API reads in the appropriate appsettings file depending on the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable:

```
`appsettings.json` (always)
`appsettings.Development.json` (if `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development`)
`appsettings.Production.json` (if `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production`)
```

But I saw some articles on the internet where people do it manually.

Like:

```
builder.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{enviroment}.json", true, true);
```

What's the reason for that? I am a bit confused. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: What you're seeing is just the **convention** and the default behavior - yes, by default, if you don't change anything, those separate JSON files will be loaded - but you can change that, if you want to / need to.

Comment: You can add `var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");` to get the environment about current project, then dynamically get value from `appsettings.Development.json` or `appsettings.Production.json`